# Can't get submit() to work

Tags: jquery

When ever I try submitting the form I either get an error, or if I type it manually in my console I get this error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var valid = 1;
        var name = $('input[name$="name"]');
        var email = $('input[name$="email"]')
        var phone = $('input[name$="phone"]');
        var comment = $('input[name$="comment"]');
        if (!name.val() && valid == 1) {
            valid = 0;
            alert('Please fill out the Name field');
            name.focus();
        }
        if (!email.val() && valid == 1) {
            valid = 0;
            alert('Please fill out the E-mail Address field');
            email.focus();
        }
        if (!phone.val() && valid == 1) {
            valid = 0;
            alert('Please fill out the Phone field');
            phone.focus();
        }
        if (valid == 1) {
            $('#contact').submit();
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're calling submit from the submit handler, so it's infinite recursion.  You want to return `true` if valid and `false` otherwise.

**Edit:** Oh, and I'm not sure you want to preventDefault in this case.

Comment: yup, .submit is like .trigger('submit') so you trigger the same event here.